# No callback events for react-native-webrtc getMediaDisplay()?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-webrtc

I have screenshare working fine on iOS using `react-native-webrtc` and `getMediaDisplay()`. I would like to know when the user actually starts the broadcast on `ScreenCapturePickerView`. Are there events that tell me when the broadcast begins or ends? I haven't found anything.